# resampling gives the error: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a time series dataframe called df. I set the index on my time variable using: df.index = df['time']
Time is an hourly increasing variable:

2012-07-19 10:00:00
2012-07-19 11:00:00
2012-07-19 12:00:00

I would like to fill my "time" missing values based on the previous one + 1h and depending on the values of another variable named "id", so I did this:

```
df['time']..groupby('LCLid').resample('H').ffill()
```

This gives me back this error:
**TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'**

I tried many things like setting a time index before resampling :

`df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])` or also: `df.set_index('time').groupby('id').resample('H', on='time').ffill()`

But Nothing seems to work. Can someone help me with this I would be very delighted?

Comment: For `resample` to work, the index must be of type `DateTime`, not `str`. Have you converted strings to DateTime?

Comment: My time values are datetime type as you see in the examples given above. In addition, I added this line before resampling: df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']) . Do I have to do it otherwise?